# Como colocar efeito ao mudar a div com Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

Gostaria de fazer uma **transição** em que, ao **clicar** em um botão, a div selecionada apareça da direita para o centro, e a que estava sendo exibida desapareça indo do centro para a esquerda **(parecendo um slide rolando na horizontal)**.

Neste código, eu consigo fazer a troca da div a ser exibida, mas não consigui fazer com transição:

```js
const slider = document.querySelectorAll('.method-slider');
const method = document.querySelectorAll('.method-title');
let currentSlide = 0;

function hideSlider() {
    slider.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('on'));
    method.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('selected'));
}

function showMethod(clicked) {
    hideSlider();
    for (let i=0; i < slider.length; i++) {
        if (clicked.id === slider[i].id) {
            slider[i].classList.add('on');
            method[i].classList.add('selected');
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.methods {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.method-title {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-grey);
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.method-title:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-purple);
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.selected {
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-purple);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #0050C9, #8041CD 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0050C9, #8041CD 50%);
  background-clip: initial;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.method-slider {
  display: none;
  transition: display 1s ease-in-out;
}

.on {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.method-slider p {
  padding-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="methods">
          <div class="method-title selected" id="tactic" onclick="showMethod(this)">Planejamento Tático</div>
          <div class="method-title" id="strategy" onclick="showMethod(this)">Planejamento Estratégico</div>
          <div class="method-title" id="operational" onclick="showMethod(this)">Planejamento Operacional</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-descriptions">
          <div class="method-slider on" id="tactic">
            <p>
            TEXTO 1
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="method-slider" id="strategy">
            <p>
              TEXTO 2
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="method-slider" id="operational">
            <p>
              TEXTO 3
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Pode ser que exista algum jeito mais fácil, e se puderem me dar uma luz, agradeço.

Comment: Considere utilizar um plugin jQuery.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode usar um recurso chamado `animation` do css para criar animações em seus componentes html. Usando o exemplo de código que você forneceu, o código se pareceria com isso:

```js
function hideSlider() {
    document
      .querySelectorAll('.method-slider.on')
      .forEach(item => item.classList.replace('on', 'off'));

    document
      .querySelectorAll('.method-title.selected')
      .forEach(item => item.classList.remove('selected'));
}

function showMethod(clicked) {
    hideSlider();

    let target = clicked.getAttribute('target');
    let slide = document.getElementById(target);

    clicked.classList.add('selected');
    slide.classList.remove('off');
    slide.classList.add('on');
}
```

```css
.methods {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.method-title {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-grey);
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.method-title:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-purple);
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.selected {
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-purple);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #0050C9, #8041CD 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0050C9, #8041CD 50%);
  background-clip: initial;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

@keyframes on {
  100% { left: 0%; }
}

@keyframes off {
  0% { left: 0%; }
  100% { left: -100%; }
}

.method-slider {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  left: 100%;
}

.on {
  animation: on 0.5s forwards;
}

.off {
  animation: off 0.5s forwards;
}

.method-slider p {
  padding-left: 80px;
}

#tactic-slide {
  background: red;
}

#strategy-slide {
  background: green;
}

#operational-slide {
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="methods">
  <div class="method-title selected" id="tactic" target="tactic-slide" onclick="showMethod(this)">Planejamento Tático</div>
  <div class="method-title" id="strategy" target="strategy-slide" onclick="showMethod(this)">Planejamento Estratégico</div>
  <div class="method-title" id="operational" target="operational-slide" onclick="showMethod(this)">Planejamento Operacional</div>
</div>
<div class="container-descriptions">
  <div class="method-slider on" id="tactic-slide">
    <p>
    TEXTO 1
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="method-slider" id="strategy-slide">
    <p>
      TEXTO 2
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="method-slider" id="operational-slide">
    <p>
      TEXTO 3
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```